# Show only integers in an enumerated list Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to output the coordinates and only the coordinates of a polyLineROI. Handles are added by the user.

```
def set_fan_curve(self):
    values = []
    p1 = pg.PolyLineROI([0,0], closed=False, invertible=False, removable=True)
    testlist = p1.getLocalHandlePositions()
    for i in enumerate(testlist):
        values.append(i)
    print(values)
```

Here is the output form the enumerated list values with 2 handles:

```
[(0, (None, Point(0.000000, 0.000000))), (1, (None, PyQt4.QtCore.QPointF(25.864716636197443, 36.0)))]
```

how can i show only the float values from each list item? The int values are x and y coordinates from plot in pyqtgraph if that helps at all. 
For example the output I am trying to get is:

```
[(0, (0.000000, 0.000000)), (1, (38.10603290676418, 48.92307692307692))]
```

Comment: Post the expected output.

Comment: Note, you can just do `values = list(enumerate(testlist))`